# Using TSQL "SELECT... WHERE LIKE" statement is giving NaN entries in the datatable using an SqlDataReader, why?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, t-sql

I am using a tsql database with a C# program I am running. I am using the following statement:

```
"SELECT Frequency, Level FROM dbo.myDB WHERE Frequency = 'some string'"
```

and then reading it into a DataTable using an SQL datareader as follows:

```
dt = new DataTable();
using(con)
{
   using(SqlCommand cmdCOunt = new SqlCommand(stmt,con))
    {
        using(sqlDataReader dr = cmdCount.ExecuteReader())
        {
           dt.Load(dr);
        }
    }
 }
```

however by doing this the 'Level' column is being populated with 'NaN'.

The data columns are both text type, though the Level column has entries in the form of negative numbers. I wonder if maybe this is causing the issue however I can't find an answer of how to solve it.

The Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RawCal] (
   [Id]   INT   IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Frequency] TEXT NULL,
   [MeasLevel] TEXT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
  );
```

Thankyou if you can offer any insight.

Comment: Have you included % in your like? `WHERE Frequency LIKE '%some string%'`

Comment: @Aureate no i have not included % is this important? the Frequency column is being populated correctly...

Comment: Please post the table definition and some sample data

Comment: In your example Frequency = 'some string' is appropriate.   So just change it so answers don't get off  topic.

Comment: @paparazzo done

Answer (score 0):

If you value is exactly `'some string'` you can use `=`

```
SELECT Frequency, Level FROM dbo.myDB WHERE Frequency = 'some string'
```

If you want a partial match, use the `%` wildcard, the below finds results where the `Frequency` *starts with* `some string`:

```
SELECT Frequency, Level FROM dbo.myDB WHERE Frequency LIKE 'some string%'
```

Or where it *contains* `some string`:

```
SELECT Frequency, Level FROM dbo.myDB WHERE Frequency LIKE '%some string%'
```

## NaN

The other thing to check is whether the `Level` field may in fact contain non-numeric values.

> The 'Level' column is being populated with 'NaN'.

That sounds like it has something that isn't a number, hence `NaN`: Not a Number.

Possibly you have a value that overflows the bounds of the type - so it might look like a number but be too large.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Level field contains only numbers (negative decimals) however they are of type text, so I don't understand why it should even be treating them as numbers? Also, I can't use Frequency = 'some string' due to incompatible types

Comment: nothing being calculated, that's pretty much it, I wouldn't know what additional code would be of any use

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is [data type text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a
>   future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Modify to `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)`.

Try a plain rdr

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdCount.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        string text1 = rdr.GetString(0);
        string text2 = rdr.GetString(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: have changed to varchar(50) and the problem persists

Comment: sorry I don't know what is rdr?

Comment: It is   SqlDataReader